# Setting up Cocos2dx project with QtCreator on Windows using LLVM

Tags: stl, llvm, cocos2d-x

I've been tasked with porting a MacOS project to Windows 10.
It consists of modified Cocos2dx library which is built as a part of the the project. The library contains several objective-c++ files, so I'm forced to use LLVM.

However, LLVM doesn't come with standard c++ library which Cocos2dx uses. I've tried pointing to MinGW include directory, I've tried installing Visual Studio and pointing to it's STL include folder, but there was always something missing.

How do I properly include STL in my project? Where do I get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up installing Visual Studio with Win10 SDK. I then used `win32-clang-msvc` mkspec. The STL was included with Win10 SDK.